How to use LLM for SQL generation over highly normalized data model
If a database table is highly normalized (no semantic column names), what instructions and context can we provide to an LLM to generate proper queries to answer user questions. The schema alone will not be sufficient to provide full context to LLM.
Assume sample like below, where too many but finite number of attributes exists.
Question to LLM could be: Is the BP of Patient 2 in normal range?



Surrogate ID
Entity ID
Attribute
Value




1
Patient1
Temperature
98.4


2
Patient1
BP-Sys
110


3
Patient1
BP-Dia
75


4
Patient2
Temperature
101.7


5
Patient2
Height
5.25


6
Patient2
Weight
123




I tried and found that regular prompt with sample data was sufficient to generate the proper query.

To help an LLM generate accurate queries for a highly normalized table, provide a schema description, mapping of attributes to their real-world meanings, and normal ranges (e.g., BP-Sys: 90-120 mmHg). Offer sample queries and outputs (e.g., "Retrieve 'BP-Sys' and 'BP-Dia' for Patient2 and check against normal ranges"). Use consistent terminology and clearly explain the context of user questions.
